# Bootstrap 4 Dropdown dropdown-item with link on left and button on the right

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap 4 and using a dropdown.

I need to have a list where the list item text / anchor is as usual...on the left and on the same line on each have a button on the right

This is what I've done but it's not right. Here's the current code:

```
 <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <div class="dropdown-item">
       <div class="float-left"><a href="#">Item 1</a></div>
       <div class="float-right">
          <button class="btn"><img class="header-btn" src="button1.png" alt="" /></button>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-item">
       <div class="float-left"><a href="#">Item 2</a></div>
       <div class="float-right">
          <button class="btn"><img class="header-btn" src="button2.png" alt="" /></button>
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

How is this done the correct way in Bootstrap 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need floats for this (floats shouldn't be used with flex in general). Just use the proper [flex properties](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/utilities/flex/#justify-content) on the item element, and remove [horizontal padding](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/utilities/spacing/).

You can probably simplify further by removing the divs from around the anchors and buttons. I've done so in the second item to demonstrate.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>

  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <div class="dropdown-item d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between px-0">
      <div><a href="#">Item 1</a></div>

      <div class="t">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="dropdown-item d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between px-0">
      <a href="#">Item 2</a>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-fQybjgWLrvvRgtW6bFlB7jaZrFsaBXjsOMm/tB9LTS58ONXgqbR9W8oWht/amnpF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Bad styling aside, with the floats what is missing is the button at the top and the dropdown wrapper.

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
Dropdown button
    </button>
```

I also added text to the image `alt="item1"` so you could actually see something (a good practice generally)

Please see the first example in the reference: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/dropdowns/

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <div class="dropdown-item">
      <div class="float-left"><a href="#">Item 1</a></div>
      <div class="float-right">
        <button class="btn"><img class="header-btn" src="button1.png" alt="item1" /></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-item">
      <div class="float-left"><a href="#">Item 2</a></div>
      <div class="float-right">
        <button class="btn"><img class="header-btn" src="button2.png" alt="item2" /></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-fQybjgWLrvvRgtW6bFlB7jaZrFsaBXjsOMm/tB9LTS58ONXgqbR9W8oWht/amnpF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: This doesn't address the question. It wasn't a matter of the dropdown not working _at all_, but just the item layout. Your code basically reproduces what was presented in the question.

Comment: @isherwood Depends on the interpretation of the OPs question - since it as it stands it does NOT work - I do agree the styling is not perfect or optimal but the question did not specify styling and does have the link left and "button" right - perhaps my interpretation of a non-specific question differs a bit. - like NOT removing the images vs doing so.

Comment: Both the title and the second paragraph make it quite clear what's being asked. Layout, not styling.